# Specify default parameter values within a hive script

Tags: hive

I am aware that it is possible to specify parameters for a hive query/script like so:

```
>hive -e "USE uk_pers_dev;set hive.cli.print.header=true;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${hiveconf:tablename} (mycol int);SELECT * FROM ${hiveconf:tablename};" -hiveconf tablename=mytable;
```

However what I would like to do is specify a default parameter value within my hive script that should be used in case no value is passed from the command-line. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

JT

Could you use

SET myvar = "Hello World"

inside your hive script do

SET myvar = COALESCE(${hiveconf:myvar},"Default");

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = ${hiveconf:myvar};

OR

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = COALESCE(${hiveconf:myvar},"Default");

Comment: Hi Al. Tried it, didn't work :(  
Here was my hql statement in my script:
SELECT "${hiveconf:myvar}" FROM myTable limit 1;
Here's what it returned:
${hiveconf:myvar}

i.e. No substitution occurred.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have a table called airports

name: string
country: string
area_code int

in HIVE I do

```
SET mycol = name;
SELECT ${hiveconf:mycol} from airports;
```

works for me.

Comment: Thanks Al, but that doesn't achieve what I need i.e. specification of a default value when no other value is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

OK So take the logic away from Hive

In POSH or a cmd file

1. Do the check
2. Substitute if needed
3. Call Hive

Maybe look at that as a wrapper.

Allan

Comment: Yep, I think that's the way to go. REPLACE() is yer friend.