# Receiving error, while using parameter in Hive Script

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to remove the hard coding from Hive script. For that I have created a hql file(`src_sys_cd_param.hql`).

Setting the source system value thru parameter, below the of param file

```
hive -f  /data/data01/dev/edl/md/sptfr/landing/src_sys_cd_param.hql;
```

param file is having command set src_sys_cd = 'M09';

After running the below script:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE SPTFR_CORE.M09_PRTY SELECT C.EDW_SK,A.PRTY_TYPE_HIER_ID,
A.PRTY_NUM,A.PRTY_DESC,A.PRTY_DESC,'N',${hiveconf:src_sys_cd},
A.DAI_UPDT_DTTM,A.DAI_CRT_DTTM 
FROM SPTFR_STG.M09_PRTY_VIEW_STG A JOIN SPTFR_STG.BKEY_PRTY_STG C 
ON ( CONCAT(A.PRTY_TYPE_LVL_1_CD,'|^',A.PRTY_NUM ,'|^',A.SRC_SYS_CD)= C.SRC_CMBN);
```

Receing the error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:113 cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hiveconf' in selection target
```

Comment: Does *"param file"* mean "shell script that runs the `hive`command"?

Comment: Look at that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511702/specify-default-parameter-values-within-a-hive-script (and a million others, just search for keywords `hive parameter`)